# Obtener un valor de un objeto PHP

Tags: php

Necesito obtener el valor que esta dentro de "code", por favor ayuda.

response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "No",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Es un json, esfuérzate un poco e investiga sobre json_decode
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También  es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder a esa propiedad del JSON, puedes usar [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) como te recomiendan en los comentarios.

El primer paso sería transformar el JSON a un string y guardarlo en un objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
$json =' {
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "No",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}' ;
```

Luego, decodificas el JSON con `json_decode` y guardas el resultado en otro objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Y por último, puedes acceder a la propiedad que estás buscando pasando primero por `'errors'`, y como esa propiedad es un array haces referencia a su primer indice con el `[0]`. Finalmente llegas a la propiedad `code` que es la que quieres:

```
print $obj->{'errors'}[0]->code;
```

Todo el código quedaría así:

```
<?php
    $json =' {
      "errors": [
        {
          "code": "InvalidInput",
          "message": "No",
          "details": ""
        }
      ]
    }' ;
    
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    
    print $obj->{'errors'}[0]->code;
?>
```

Ejecútalo y pruébalo [aquí](https://paiza.io/projects/vzYH1ahUTl7r1tVPBMRGHg).